# User experience Web forms: show many items and details

Tags: website-design, forms

I'm working on project to show every item with its deposit 
every item should refer to its deposit in some way

lets assume that the item is parent and the deposit is the child, i want to show all items, when the user refer to specific item the program will give him in which deposit this item is in?

> i'm talking about many items(like a thousand item).

i'm using web forms c# asp.net on visual studio 2015.

Comment: I'm not really clear what it is you're looking for an answer to here. Please can you elaborate.

Comment: Also - do you search for a solution for the programmatical problem or rather for how to display information? If the second is the case, what is your approach?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? It's very unclear what the question is.